# Persist state with react-navigation AppContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I updated react-navigation for a react-native project from v2.x to v3.x. For the v2.x I had this rendered at root:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...})

const App = () => <AppNavigator persistenceKey={"NavigationState"} />;

export default App;
```

I need to persist the state, thats why I used `persistenceKey`

For the v3.x of react-navigation an app container is required, but I'm having problems figuring out how to implement the same state persistence.

This is my new code with the v3.x

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

const App = () => <AppContainer />;

export default App;
```

How do I persist the state this way?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...})

const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"
  const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
    } catch(err) {
      // handle the error according to your needs
    }
  }
  const loadNavigationState = async () => {
    const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
    return JSON.parse(jsonString)
  }

const AppNavigationPersists = () => <AppNavigator
  persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState}
  loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState}
/>

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigationPersists)

export default AppContainer;
```

but I get this error:

`Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to update `react-navigation` to `>= 3.10.0`.

Per the [`react-navigation` changelog](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/14e2df66d5b6e1f670e0afd633a0460b5d95220b/CHANGELOG.md#3100---2019-05-16), they only now only support `persistNavigationState` and `loadNavigationState` on `react-navigation@^3.10`.

You can still use `persistenceKey` on versions lower than `3.10`.

---EDIT---

An example of a version `<3.10.0`:

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...})

const App = () => <AppNavigator persistenceKey={"NavigationState"} />;

export default App;
```

An example implementation for a version `>= 3.10.0`:

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"
const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
  } catch(err) {
    // handle the error according to your needs
  }
}
const loadNavigationState = async () => {
  const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
  return JSON.parse(jsonString)
}

const App = () => <AppNavigator persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState} loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState} />;
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and used the latest v2.x version. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. You can persist state with React Navigation 3.10 and greater, but how to use it in conjunction with `createAppContainer` is unclear, and unfortunately this is the top result on Google.

Comment: @Slbox to clarify, `persistenceKey` has been replaced by two functions, `persistNavigationState` and `loadNavigationState`.

`persistNavigationState` receives as an argument the current navigation state, and you will need to implement storage of of the navigation state

`loadNavigationState` receives no argument, and needs to return the navigation state as a JSON

Comment: Thanks for editing this post! It'll save a lot of people a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [docs example for v3.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html#usage).

> ```
> const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
>   const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"
>   const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
>     try {
>       await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
>     } catch(err) {
>       // handle the error according to your needs
>     }
>   }
>   const loadNavigationState = async () => {
>     const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
>     return JSON.parse(jsonString)
>   }
>
>  const App = () => <AppNavigator persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState} loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState} />;
> ```

To solve the problem in `const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)` what you can do is create another component that return `AppNavigator` with the persistence.

```
const AppNavigationPersists = () => <AppNavigator 
    persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState} 
    loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState} 
/>
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigationPersists)
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion but a get this error: `Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined`. Is related to the NavigationContainer

Comment: Hummm, that is weird, don't know how to help more

Comment: I only wrap AppNavigator with 
    const AppNavigator = createAppContainer( createStackNavigator({...}) );

Comment: It worked for me when I passed `persistNavigationState` and `loadNavigationState` to AppContainer instead of AppNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it the same way as in the example. In my case I forgot to update react-navigation to version ^3.11.0 and I also forgot to import AsyncStorage. Somehow react native wasn't complaining about AsyncStorage not being there. This is why the state persistence didn't seem to work.

```
import {
  AsyncStorage
} from "react-native";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"

const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
  } catch(err) {
    // handle the error according to your needs
  }
}

const loadNavigationState = async () => {
  const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
  return JSON.parse(jsonString)
}

const App = () => <AppContainer persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState} loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState}  renderLoadingExperimental={() => <ActivityIndicator />}/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc is not clear but you actually need to pass the props `persistNavigationState` and `loadNavigationState` directly to the AppContainer component:

```
<AppContainer
  persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState}
  loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `createAppContainer` with react navigation 4, here is the solution which worked for me.

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {

    const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"
    const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
        } catch(err) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    const loadNavigationState = async () => {
        const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
        return JSON.parse(jsonString)
    }
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000'}}>
            <AppContainer
                persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState}
                loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```